# Getting Container Error while publishing inside docker file

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am building the docker image with .NET7- in Azure Devops with ubuntu-latest agent. all the previous layers untill the publish are successful.but, while publishing the dll, I am getting the below error.

> /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.build.containers/0.4.0/build/Microsoft.NET.Build.Containers.targets(195,5):
> error CONTAINER1012: The local daem
> on is not available, but pushing to
> a local daemon was requested. Please start the daemon and try again.

Here is the docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /source
COPY ["src/TestAPI/TestAPI.csproj", "src/TestAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/TestAPI/TestAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/source/src/TestAPI"
RUN dotnet build "TestAPI.csproj" -c Release

FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR /source/src/TestAPI
RUN dotnet publish "TestAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
```

Here is the error from Azure Devops

> MSBuild version 17.6.1+8ffc3fe3d for .NET   Determining projects to
> restore...   All projects are up-to-date for restore.   TestAPI ->
> /source/src/TestAPI/bin/Release/net7.0/TestAPI.dll   TestAPI ->
> /app/publish/   Building image 'testwebapi' with tags 1.1.0 on top of
> base image mcr.microsoft.com:443/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
> /root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.build.containers/0.4.0/build/Microsoft.NET.Build.Containers.targets(195,5):
> error CONTAINER1012: The local daemon is not available, but pushing to
> a local daemon was requested. Please start the daemon and try again.
> [/source/src/TestAPI/TestAPI.csproj] The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet
> publish "TestAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish' returned a
> non-zero code: 1
> ##[error]The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet publish "TestAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish' returned a non-zero code: 1

Here is the pipeline details

```
variables:
- group: TestAPI_Group
- name:  imageRepository
  value: "TestAPIsvc"
- name: dockerfilePath
  value: "Dockerfile"
- name: vmImageName
  value: "ubuntu-latest"
- name: BuildConfiguration
  value: "Release"
- name: tag
  value: "1.0.0"


trigger:
- master

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build stage
    jobs: 
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)

        steps:
        - checkout: self
          persistCredentials: true

        - task: Docker@2
          displayName: 'Build TestAPISvc Image'
          inputs:
            repository: '$(imageRepository)'
            buildContext: '**'
            command: build
            Dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
            tags: $(tag)
```

Comment: please share your pipeline file.

Comment: please share whole pipleline yaml

Comment: Added the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to sove the issue. This issue is we are trying to test the new feature introduced in .NET7 where we can build docker image without docker file, that was enabled and also I have docker file which I used to build in Azure devops, somewhere there is interoperable issue. I have changed this settings in Directory.build.props file at solution level.

```
 <PropertyGroup>
      <!--<PublishProfile>DefaultContainer</PublishProfile>
      <ContainerImageTags>1.1.0</ContainerImageTags>-->
    </PropertyGroup>
```

commented these two and it started working.